# rich:calendar not triggering f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I'm new to jsf, and I'm writing my first application using richfaces. I'm having trouble with the ajax tag that I use to update the associated managed bean property on server for rich:calendar components. This is the code:

```
<rich:panel header="Computing Options">
            <h4>Time Interval</h4>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%">
                <h:outputText value="From" />
                <rich:calendar id="intervalFrom" value="#{scenarioEditor.intervalFrom}" popup="true" showApplyButton="true" datePattern="yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm">
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@this" event="change" render="outFrom" />
                </rich:calendar>
                <h:outputText value="To" />
                <rich:calendar id="intervalTo" value="#{scenarioEditor.intervalTo}" popup="true" showApplyButton="true" datePattern="yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm">
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@this" event="change" render="outTo" />
                </rich:calendar>
                <h:outputText id="outFrom" value="From: #{scenarioEditor.intervalFrom}" />
                <h:outputText id="outTo" value="To: #{scenarioEditor.intervalTo}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h4>Algorithms</h4>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{scenarioEditor.visibilityClashes}" id="clash" >
                    <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <h:outputLabel value="Visibility Clashes Evaluator" for="clash" style="width:170px" />
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{scenarioEditor.xBandInterference}" id="xband" >
                    <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <h:outputLabel value="X-Band Interferences Evaluator" for="xband" style="width:170px"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:panel>
```

checkboxes works fine, but the calendars do not. Why? I`ve tried both f:ajax and a4j:ajax without luck.

To better clarify, I want that right after the user has finished entering a value into the calendar, an ajax request is made that call the setter method for the associated property. And this, for the calendar does not happen while for the checkboxes, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax event is failing because of **T** in `datePattern="yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"` is not a [valid date formatting pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If you add a `<rich:messages/>` component to your field, you'll see that a conversion error is occurring on each ajax request. Remove the `T` and you'll be fine

Comment: thank you. It worked! And I've learned to add a rich:messages to my pages too! >D